# Why is this attempt to label ggplot plot bars with geom_text not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart, geom-text

I'd like to show the mean value of each bar near the top of the bar plot a bit like the image below from [this post](https://thomasadventure.blog/posts/labels-ggplot2-bar-chart/).

[image: image of correctly labeled bar plot]

I'm using the `geom_text` code from that post, but the plot is placing the variable's values all over the bars rather than just one mean value per bar the top of the bar.

```
ggplot(data=SocratesPreStudyApproved, aes(x=PlatformOrder, y=ReflectiveReflectionTest, fill=PlatformOrder))+ 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, position = "dodge", color="black")+
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge", width=.2)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", comparisons = PlatformComparisons, label = "p.signif")+
  facet_wrap(~ReasoningPhilosophyOrder, scales="fixed", strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Analyzing only approved participants (excluding rejected)",
       x = "Platform within each condition order",
       y = "Reflective responses to reasoning items (with lures)")+
  scale_fill_grey(start = .6, end = 1)+
  geom_text(aes(label = ReflectiveReflectionTest))
```

[image: bar plot with numbers up the y-axis]

Adding X and Y values for geom_text doesn't seem to help, e.g.,

```
geom_text(aes(x=PlatformOrder, y=ReflectiveReflectionTest, label = ReflectiveReflectionTest))
```

**Question**

How do I get just one numeric label per bar (that is the mean value of that bar, which is also the height of the bar on the y-axis)?

(I've installed and loaded all of the packages from the post, but not found a solution.)

Comment: Please add a reproducible dataset for us to better help you. Try the dput() function to help you get one. That said, the stat_summary() functions you are using do calculate a mean out of a range of values, but the geom_text() functions do not. In other words, geom_text() is plotting all observations. So you probably will need to add instructions calculate the mean you want to display as text.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, as is [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509493/1701844)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler version of your question using a built-in data set.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, wt, label = wt)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, position = "dodge", color="black") +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

I've told the bar layer to calculate the mean `wt` and show that for each `carb`. Meanwhile, the text layer is receiving data for all the component elements and using their `wt` values as the y and label.

One option would be to make the text layer perform the same summary calculation.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, wt, label = wt)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, color="black") +
  # note: the ..y.. here tells ggplot to use the value after the summary calc
  stat_summary(aes(label=..y..), vjust = 0, geom = "text", fun = mean, color="black")
```

[image]

My personal preference would be to perform the summarization before ggplot, like this, resulting in a simpler plotting call for the same output:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  summarize(wt = mean(wt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carb, wt, label = wt)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = 0)
```